# How to periodically update a date/time value on a page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this example, I have an input text field that contains a datetime value set with jQuery.

**http://jsfiddle.net/D4Hu9/**

HTML:

```
<input id="foo" name="foo" type="text" value="" size="55" />
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    var now = new Date();
     jQuery('#foo').val(now.toString());        
});
```

How can I update this value every 5 seconds from jQuery?

Answer (score 9):

```
function updateTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    jQuery('#foo').val(now.toString());        
}

setInterval(updateTime, 5000); // 5 * 1000 miliseconds
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/28Tgz/1/