# How to output continous time on a page using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have been using php `<?php echo date('d-M-y H:i:s'); ?>`.

But the problem is that time changes only on page refresh. How can one achieve this in jquery continously updating time even without page refresh?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to periodically update a date/time value on a page using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084051/how-to-periodically-update-a-date-time-value-on-a-page-using-jquery)

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the time in JavaScript using `Date.now()` and updating the element on the page with the latest time. Then format `Date.now()` to whatever your format is. Here's an example:

```
<span id="myTime"><?php echo date('d-M-y H:i:s'); ?></span>

<script>
    setInterval(function(){
       document.getElementById('myTime').innerHTML = Date(Date.now()); //The outer Date is used to format the time loosely. There are better ways to do formatting :)
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but is there a way one can only show the time and date alone  (date and time alone without showing the timezone)

Comment: Yeah, there's all kinds of ways to format the date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. If the answer is correct would you mind marking it so? Thanks!